# Which type of sums of squares does lm-function in R use?

Tags: r, ancova, function, sums-of-squares

I ran a two-way ANCOVA in R:

```
ancova = lm(DV ~ IV1*IV2 + CV1 + CV2 + CV3, data = Data)
summary.aov(ancova)
```

Anybody know if this uses type III sums of squares?

I know that the anova() and aov() functions use type I, but I am trying to get type III.

Comment: Common ways to type III- ANOVA is through packages such as afex as in https://www.psychologie.uni-heidelberg.de/ae/meth/team/mertens/blog/anova_in_r_made_easy.nb.html or ez as in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ez/versions/3.0-1/topics/ezANOVA

Answer (score 1):

Using the Anova function in the car package you can specify type II or type III tests

```
library(car)
Anova(model,type=3)
```